# Validation function for add to cart form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

We've added some custom fields into the add to cart form within Shopify and are trying to add some validation. We've written our custom validation function and are trying to bind it using the following code placed which we placed in theme.liquid within the body tag:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#AddToCartForm').submit(function() {
      console.log("Validation called");
      return false;
  });
});
```

We've modified the form add to cart form to have the AddToCartForm id. However, this function is never called. Logging the just $('#AddToCartForm') shows that the selector is working correctly. We also tried moving it to the product liquid page to be just under the form close tag, but that didn't change anything. We've also tried binding onto the submit button itself then using

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

to stop the form from submitting, but this also does not work. However, it does bind and the function is called properly, it just doesn't stop the submission. We've been trying all day to fix this, and are completely out of ideas, any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:

We also actually also tried using onSubmit, so the code was:

```
<form onSubmit='return test()'>
```

The js was:

```
function test() {
  console.log("Validation called");
  return false;
}
```

this function was also never called.

Another thing we've tried is changing the add to cart button to:

```
<button type="button" name="add" id="AddToCart" class="btn">
```

from

```
<button type="submit" name="add" id="AddToCart" class="btn">
```

Then calling $('#AddToCartForm').submit() if validations pass, the major issue with this is the fact that someone can just call $('#AddToCartForm').submit() from console to submit the form and bypass all validations..

Our current validation script is:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#AddToCart').click(function(e) { //Changed this to the ID of the submit button and changed .submit to .click
    console.log(e);
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var formIsValid = true;
    var message = "Please fill this out and you will be able to add the item to your cart.";
    /* Changed this to the ID of the form itself */ $('#AddToCartForm').find('[name^="properties"]').filter('.required, [required="required"]').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('error');
      if (formIsValid && $(this).val() == '') {
        formIsValid = false;
        message = $(this).attr('data-error') || message;
        $(this).addClass('error');
      }
    });
    if (formIsValid){
      $('#AddToCartForm').submit();
      return true;
    }
    else {
      alert(message);
      return false;
    }
  }).find('input, select, textarea').focus(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('error');
  });
});
```

It's based upon: https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/products/get-customization-information-for-products#require-fields and https://gist.github.com/carolineschnapp/11167400

HTML for the shopify form is:

```
<form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="AddToCartForm">
  <select name="id" id="productSelect" class="product-single__variants">
    {% for variant in product.variants %}
    <option {% unless variant.available %} disabled="disabled" {% endunless %} {% if variant == current_variant %} selected="selected" {% endif %} data-sku="{{ variant.sku }}" value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }} - {% if variant.available %}{{ variant.price | money_with_currency }}{% else %}{{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}{% endif %}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>

  <div class="product-single__quantity{% unless settings.product_quantity_enable %} is-hidden{% endunless %}">
    <label for="Quantity">{{ 'products.product.quantity' | t }}</label>
    <input type="number" id="Quantity" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" class="quantity-selector">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" name="add" id="AddToCart" class="btn">
    <span id="AddToCartText">{{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Change your "submit" to "button" and use `.on('click',function()...`. After validation use `$('#form_id').submit()`.

Comment: That works, but it's no longer an AJAX call as the add to cart was before. Any idea why?

Comment: On top of that, unfortunately someone can just type in $('AddToCartForm').submit() in console to bypass validations, any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Can you share the full form code and the full validation function?

Comment: I've added it to the original post

Comment: Just want to point out this is what we've changed it to now because .submit refuses to work.

Comment: Can you also share the HTML of the form?

Comment: I know that this post is very old but a lot of people still have this problem. I have spent days trying o get the Debut theme to remain on the product page rather than redirect to the cart. There are several versions of "ajaxify-cart" knocking around, but none of these currently work, at least on the Debut theme. However, thanks to the comment from Samuel Ellis below I just found something that works and wanted to share this in the hope that it will help.

Comment: Open theme.js and look for 

_addItemToCart: function(data, redirectUrl) {

Within this function you will find the following code:

window.location.href = redirectUrl;

Simply comment the line out to prevent the redirect. You will then need to add code to update the cart count at the top right of the theme, but there are plenty of example online that include how to do this. To test it before you add that code simply refresh the page to see the cart count update.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by going old school javascript function.

```
function checkForm() {       
   //What ever you want to check
   console.log("Validation called");
   return false;
}
```

and in the form call the function with return

```
<form id="AddToCartForm" action="" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
..
</form>
```

Comment: I actually just edited my original post to include that we tried this. It also didn't work unfortunately. The function was never called.

Comment: (function(){
    // Your JavaScript here
   function checkForm() {       
   //What ever you want to check
   console.log("Validation called");
   return false;
}
})();

Try this.

Comment: jQuery(function($) {
  function test() {
   console.log("called");
    return false;
  }
});

Still failed.

(function(){ function checkForm() { console.log("Validation called"); return false; } })();

also fails. I did update onSubmit with the correct function names both times.

Comment: just try it without jQuery tag..

(function(){ 
// Your JavaScript here 
function checkForm() { 
//What ever you want to check 
console.log("Validation called"); 
return false; } })();

Comment: Tried it without the jQuery tag as well. Still didn't work. :( The code I used is:

(function(){ 
  function checkForm() { 
    console.log("Validation called"); 
    return false; 
  }
})();


          <form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="AddToCartForm" onSubmit='return checkForm()'>

Comment: use "onsubmit" in the form. not "onSubmit". and use the old school function that i answered with.

Comment: Just tried it. Still not working. 

          <form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="AddToCartForm" onsubmit='return checkForm()'>


function checkForm() {       
   //What ever you want to check
   console.log("Validation called");
   return false;
}

Answer (score 0):

Something appears to be wrong with your form fields and the functions assigned. Here is the shortened version.

```
$(function(){
  $('form').on('submit',function() {
    var formIsValid = true;
    var message = "Please fill this out and you will be able to add the item to your cart.";
    $(this).find('[name^="properties"]').filter('.required, [required="required"]').each(function() { // Filter appears to be wrong here. Since you are going with manual form validation, use class="required" instead of attribute "required" in form HTML
      $(this).removeClass('error');
      if (formIsValid && $(this).val() == '') {
        formIsValid = false;
        message = $(this).attr('data-error') || message;
        $(this).addClass('error');
      }
    });
    if (!formIsValid) alert(message)
    return formIsValid
  }).find('input, select, textarea').focus(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('error');
  });
})
```

Try it out: https://jsfiddle.net/xewsw2t8/8/

Comment: I've added the html for the form within shopify into the original post. Copy pasting your exact code and just adding in a console.log at the front of the function to show that its called, yet its never is called..

Comment: The form is working fine with me. Something else is the issue. Can you share the live page link so I can see it for myself?

Comment: Did you try it within shopify itself? Here is the base product without our customizations to the HTML of the form: https://haris-test-shop.myshopify.com/products/test This is the product with our HTML customizations to the form: https://haris-test-shop.myshopify.com/products/hari-test-product The password to the shop is: schait

Comment: As expected, there is another function assigned to cart submit that is overriding this function. Let me see what can be done about it.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify does indeed override all form submission events, which is extremely frustrating. I ended up trying to trace the contact form (simplest one) to find out where these mysterious AJAX calls were coming from that were bullying my on submit code. Turns out they come from the **app.js.liquid** file. Here's the contact form example:

```
  var $notify_form = $('.notify_form .contact-form');
  $notify_form.each(function() {
    var $nf = $(this);
    $nf.on("submit", function (e) {
      if($nf.find('.notify_email').val() != "") {
        $.ajax({
            type: $nf.attr('method'),
            url: $nf.attr('action'),
            data: $nf.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
              $notify_form.fadeOut("slow", function(){
                $nf.prev('.message').html({{ 'products.notify_form.post_success' | t | json }});
              });
            }
        });
      } else {
        $nf.prev('.message').html({{ 'products.notify_form.post_error' | t | json }});
      }  
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

Following the precise structure above led me to a working solution for my form validation. Hope this helps out!