# How to prevent entering space only in a text field on Shopify website

Tags: javascript, html, validation, shopify, liquid

I have input text boxes on my website to allow products to be personalised.

The fields must contain some text but some customers workaround this by just entering a space and submitting the form. This is a problem as the personalisation can't be left blank and has to be some text value, even if it's just a dot or a hyphen, for example.

**How do I prevent the form being submitted where the text box only has a single space as the only character that has been entered?**

The code is Liquid as it's a Shopify e-commerce store

```
    <div class="personalisation_label">
    <p>Type the personalisation you want below:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="personalisation">
    <input type="text" name="properties[Line 1]" id="Line 1-0-0" maxlength="12" size="12">
    <button type="submit" name="add" id="AddToCart" class="btn {{ btn_class }}{% if section.settings.enable_payment_button %} btn--secondary{% endif %}">
    <span id="AddToCartText">{{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}</span>
    </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Show us your code, so we can help you

Comment: What's your backend or how do you submit this form? Validating on the front end is not the safest.

Comment: Have you seen <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714579/how-do-i-prevent-a-leading-space-from-being-entered-in-a-textbox>

Comment: If your customers don't want their product/purchase to be personalised why do you want to force them? That question is irrelevant to the programming question you're asking, but I do think you - or the business owners - need to consider the question.

Comment: IvanD, i'll try to do that in a moment. Zsolt, the code is Liquid as it's a Shopify e-commerce store. Sonal, yes but its not quite the same as this is about when a customer enters only a space and nothing else. David, it's complicated to go into, but due to the nature of the product, the lines of text that the input boxes relate to, really do need to contain at least 1 character (not just a space)

Comment: maybe this can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39629708/7417402

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<button type="submit" name="add" id="AddToCart" onclick="return validate();" ... rest of the HTML
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function validate() {
   var text = document.getElementById("Line 1-0-0").value;
   if (!text.replace(/\s/g, '').length) {
       return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @or-assayag but that seems to prevent spaces being entered completely. i want to allow users to be able to enter spaces between words, but not just enter a space as the only character in the text box.

Comment: Hey, updated my answer, hopefully it will work.

Comment: Thank you @or-assayag. That should work fine

Comment: Good to hear. glad to help, please upvote and mark answer as accepted. Thanks and good luck :)

Comment: Thanks. One last question. In order to display a dialog box message to the user when they have only entered a space in the textbox is the following correct:  `code` function validate() {
   var text = document.getElementById("Line 1-0-0").value;
   if (!text.replace(/\s/g, '').length) { alert ( "This line cannot be left blank");
       return false;
   } 
   return true;
}

Comment: Please create a new question in StackOverFlow.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using plain HTML5 form validation?

If you want to disallow value consisting entirely from whitespace characters:

```html
<input type="text" name="properties[Line 1]" id="Line 1-0-0" maxlength="12" size="12"
       pattern="\s*[^\s]+\s*" />
```

In this example:

- `\s` means whitespace character class
- `\s*` matches any number of whitespace characters (including no characters at all)
- `[^\s]+` matches at sequence of at least one non-whitespace character
- and the final `\s*` matches any whitespace in the end of the input

Combined they allow user to enter anything except empty string and a string consisting entirely from whitespace.

Alternatively, if you want users to use only Latin letters:

```html
<input type="text" name="properties[Line 1]" id="Line 1-0-0" maxlength="12" size="12"
       pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" />
```

see documentation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#Validating_against_a_regular_expression

**P.S.** please do think about the business problem that you are trying to solve. Your end goal is probably not to get the perfectly formatted input in your CRM but paying customers.

If I were in your shoes I'd try to understand why your customers do not want to specify personalisation and put spaces instead.

Maybe they don't need it? Maybe they do not care? Maybe they don't want to think or not sure what to specify when making an order? Maybe they need time to think? Maybe they are not willing to commit to specific phrasing just yet?

As a shop owner, I'd let customer put whatever they want in any field as long as they are making an order and paying for it. Adding extra hurdles on the checkout path will hurt the conversion funnel.

If you really want your customers to use personalisation, follow up with them via email or phone **after they make an order** and ask them what they want to put in there and tell them that this is optional and they have time to think.

Comment: Please read @masted75 comment to my answer, he wants to validate that the input is not just spaces.